# Using .htaccess to rewrite to Wordpress subdirectory?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

As opposed to many questions here in StackOverflow, I'm looking for something a little different.  I have a Wordpress install in a subfolder of my domain called "blog". The main part of the website is a Magento website. I'm looking to take any instance where "blog" is part of the URI, and make sure it's untouched by the myriad of other RewriteRules in Apache.

**As a few examples:**

**http://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/**

**http://www.example.com/blog/**

**http://www.example.com/blog/save-money-groceries-without-coupons/**

...should all direct to the Wordpress site found under */blog/*

**http://www.example.com/**

**http://www.example.com/plumbing/faucets.html**

**http://www.example.com/about/family-history.html**

...should all direct to the Magento site that is currently found under the root directory

What is the best practice in writing the .htaccess file to achieve this result?

Comment: Vinnie,can you tell me ,are you using  fighping magento extension for intregate???

Comment: No, we are not. We have a few extensions, but my boss and I have never heard of the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect `http://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/` to `http://www.blog.example.com/wp-admin/` you can add the following to the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.blog.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on setting up Apache servers but I think you want your WordPress install in a completely different folder to Magento and then use `Alias` in your `.conf` file. You can read about the `Alias` directive [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html).

For example in my Apache .conf files I have

```
Alias /blog/ "/full/path/to/wordpress/htdocs/"
```

This way the folder `/full/path/to/wordpress/htdocs/` has its own `.htaccess` and its own `index.php` - which is what you are going to want for running WordPress without jumping through hoops.

Remember to restart Apache if you update the `.conf` file.